# Neo4J Cypher - Case Insensitive MERGE

Tags: neo4j, cypher, case-insensitive

Is there a way to do a case insensitive MERGE in Cypher (Neo4J)?

I'm creating a graph of entities I have been able to extract from a set of documents, and want to merge entities that are the same across multiple documents (accepting the risk that the same name doesn't mean it's the same entity!). The issue is that the case can vary between documents.

At the moment, I'm using the MERGE syntax to create merged nodes, but it is sensitive to the differences in case. How can I perform a case-insensitive merge?

Comment: hey did you get a solution? did you get a chance to try out the solutions suggested below?

Comment: In the end, none of the proposed solutions met our requirements so we changes our schema to include a labelled node that contains the upper-cased value which we can merge on, whilst still retaining the case information on the original mode. E.g. (OriginalCase)-[uppercased]->(ORIGINALCASE)

Comment: you can post that as an answer and mark your question resolved. So that it will be helpful to someone else too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution we found was to change our schema to include a labelled node that contains the upper-cased value which we can merge on, whilst still retaining the case information on the original mode. E.g. (OriginalCase)-[uppercased]->(ORIGINALCASE)

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct way but you can try out something like below.MERGE is made for pattern matching and labels of different cases constitute different patterns

```
MERGE (a:Crew123)
WITH a,labels(a) AS t
LIMIT 1
MATCH (n)
WHERE [l IN labels(n) 
  WHERE lower(l)=lower(t[0])] AND a <> n
WITH a,collect(n) AS s
FOREACH (x IN s | 
         DELETE a)
RETURN *
```

The above query will give you an `ERROR` but it will delete the newly created node if a similar label exists. You can add additional pattern in the MERGE clause . And in case there are no similar labels it will run successfully.

Again this is just a work around to not allow new similar labels.

Answer (score 1):

If the data is coming for instance from a CSV or similar source (parameter) you can use a dedicated, consistent case property for the merge and set the original value separately.

e.g.

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (u:User) ASSERT u.iname IS UNIQUE;

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "http://some/url" AS line
WITH line, lower(line.name) as iname
MERGE (u:User {iname:iname}) ON CREATE SET u.name = line.name;
```